# How to store Array of multipe types with realm in react native

Tags: react-native, realm

When using realm, if i need to store filed with value like [783, "Name of"],

This is my code, when i use mixed i got null,

```
export const Schema = {
  name: 'Schema',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'int',
    name: {type: 'string', indexed: true},
    field: 'string[]', // mixed[] not work too
  }
}
```

Any help please !!!

Comment: The question is really unclear. Realm does not have an Array type - it has a List which can be a managed Realm object. Also, Lists in Realm are homogenous - so they cannot store "multiple types". You can however, store another Realm object in an array, and they object can contain properties but again, any one property will be homogenous. Perhaps you can clarify what your asking, and explain what you're trying to do (e.g. what's the use case?)

Comment: Hi @jay 

I need to store an array recived from server (format: [783, "Name of item"]),

Comment: You cannot store an array in Realm. You would need to craft another Realm object, call it `MyData` for example, and have its properties store the number `783` and the string `Name of item`. The in the main object add a `List` property (as mentioned above) to store a List of the MyData objects. It would probably help you to go through the Realm [React Getting Started Guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/#std-label-react-native-intro)

Comment: First of all, Thanks 

another question please, can i override the constructor of MyData object, to auto setting  values ?

e.g: setter will convert [783, "Name of"] to {id: 783, name: "Name of"} ?

If yes, how can i deal with this case ?

Comment: Yes. Realm object properties can have default values. Please see the Getting Started Guide [Define Schema](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/#define-an-object-schema) for an example. You can see in that example the property `name` has a default value of `Cat`.

Comment: @Jay no, i don't mean default values, but setters & getters or override constructor to handle object

Comment: e.g: 

`constructor (values) {
this.id = values[0]
}`

Comment: That sounds like a separate and discreet question - please keep questions and comments on topic and if you have another question, please post it and we'll take a look